# How to display columns as rows in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display exam results form simple database containing two tables `tblStudents` and `tblExamResults`.

`tblstudents` contains student ID and Full_Name columns

In `tblexamResults` columns are Student_id, Subject and Marks.

as in below Picture

[image: tblstudents]

1- Currently I am displaying Student results using this query

```
SELECT     tblStudents.Full_Name, tblExamResults.Subject, tblExamResults.Marks
FROM         tblExamResults INNER JOIN
                      tblStudents ON tblExamResults.Student_id = tblStudents.Student_ID
order by tblStudents.Full_Name
```

2 - And results looks like in the following picture:

[image]

3 - But what I want is to display each subject as row and get result of each subject below it

So that each student's result is displayed in the same row:

*Student_Name*   *sub1_result*   *sub2_Result*   *sub3_Result*

Like in the following picture (Excel screenshot)

[image]

So:

- How I can display data in that format?
- Is that possible in SQL Server?

Comment: search for `CROSS TAB`, `PIVOT` and `DYNAMIC SQL`

Comment: Use dynamic pivot concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select fullname,[english] english, [history] history, [physics] physics
from 
(
  select fullname,subject,marks
  from (yourquery)
) src
pivot
(
  max(marks)
  for subject in ([english], [history], [physics])
) piv;
```

or

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.subject) 
            FROM (yourquery) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT fullname, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select fullname,subject,marks
                from (your query)
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(marks)
                for subject in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
fullname english history physics
    a   85  70  60
    i   60  100 89
    s   90  90  99
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've used next part of @Chanukya Answer with little Changes
in that Answer i was getting error at line 5 becouse of parentheses in `FROM (yourquery) c`

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.subject) 
            FROM tblExamResults c   ' parentheses Removed from (tblExamResults) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
       print(@cols)
     set @query = '
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT     tblStudents.Full_Name, tblExamResults.Subject, tblExamResults.Marks
FROM         tblExamResults INNER JOIN
                      tblStudents ON tblExamResults.Student_id = tblStudents.Student_ID
) as s
PIVOT
(
    sum(marks) FOR subject IN ('+ @cols +')
)AS pvt'
;
execute(@query)
```